# Curve fitting in Scipy with 3d data and parameters

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am working on fitting a 3d distribution function in scipy.  I have a numpy array with counts in x- and y-bins, and I am trying to fit that to a rather complicated 3-d distribution function.  The data is fit to 26 (!) parameters, which describe the shape of its two constituent populations.

I learned here that I have to pass my x- and y-coordinates as 'args' when I call leastsq.  The code presented by unutbu works as written for me, but when I try to apply it to my specific case, I am given the error "TypeError: leastsq() got multiple values for keyword argument 'args' "

Here's my code (sorry for the length):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as spopt
from textwrap import wrap
import collections

cl = 0.5
ch = 3.5
rl = -23.5
rh = -18.5
mbins = 10
cbins = 10

def hist_data(mixed_data, mbins, cbins):
    import numpy as np
    H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(mixed_data[:,1], mixed_data[:,2], bins = (mbins, cbins), weights = mixed_data[:,3])
    x, y = 0.5 * (xedges[:-1] + xedges[1:]), 0.5 * (yedges[:-1] + yedges[1:])
    return H.T, x, y

def gauss(x, s, mu, a):
    import numpy as np
    return a * np.exp(-((x - mu)**2. / (2. * s**2.)))

def tanhlin(x, p0, p1, q0, q1, q2):
    import numpy as np
    return p0 + p1 * (x + 20.) + q0 * np.tanh((x - q1)/q2)

def func3d(p, x, y):
    import numpy as np
    from sys import exit
    rsp0, rsp1, rsq0, rsq1, rsq2, rmp0, rmp1, rmq0, rmq1, rmq2, rs, rm, ra, bsp0, bsp1, bsq0, bsq1, bsq2, bmp0, bmp1, bmq0, bmq1, bmq2, bs, bm, ba = p
x, y = np.meshgrid(coords[0], coords[1])
    rs = tanhlin(x, rsp0, rsp1, rsq0, rsq1, rsq2)
    rm = tanhlin(x, rmp0, rmp1, rmq0, rmq1, rmq2)
    ra = schechter(x, rap, raa, ram) # unused
    bs = tanhlin(x, bsp0, bsp1, bsq0, bsq1, bsq2)
    bm = tanhlin(x, bmp0, bmp1, bmq0, bmq1, bmq2)
    ba = schechter(x, bap, baa, bam) # unused
    red_dist = ra / (rs * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * gauss(y, rs, rm, ra)
    blue_dist = ba / (bs * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * gauss(y, bs, bm, ba)
    result = red_dist + blue_dist
return result

def residual(p, coords, data):
    import numpy as np
    model = func3d(p, coords)
    res = (model.flatten() - data.flatten())
    # can put parameter restrictions in here
    return res

def poiss_err(data):
    import numpy as np
    return np.where(np.sqrt(H) > 0., np.sqrt(H), 2.)

# =====

H, x, y = hist_data(mixed_data, mbins, cbins)

data = H

coords = x, y
# x and y will be the projected coordinates of the data H onto the plane z = 0

# x has bins of width 0.5, with centers at -23.25, -22.75, ... , -19.25, -18.75
# y has bins of width 0.3, with centers at 0.65, 0.95, ... , 3.05, 3.35    

Param = collections.namedtuple('Param', 'rsp0 rsp1 rsq0 rsq1 rsq2 rmp0 rmp1 rmq0 rmq1 rmq2 rs rm ra bsp0 bsp1 bsq0 bsq1 bsq2 bmp0 bmp1 bmq0 bmq1 bmq2 bs bm ba')
p_guess = Param(rsp0 = 0.152, rsp1 = 0.008, rsq0 = 0.044, rsq1 = -19.91, rsq2 = 0.94, rmp0 = 2.279, rmp1 = -0.037, rmq0 = -0.108, rmq1 = -19.81, rmq2 = 0.96, rs = 1., rm = -20.5, ra = 10000., bsp0 = 0.298, bsp1 = 0.014, bsq0 = -0.067, bsq1 = -19.90, bsq2 = 0.58, bmp0 = 1.790, bmp1 = -0.053, bmq0 = -0.363, bmq1 = -20.75, bmq2 = 1.12, bs = 1., bm = -20., ba = 2000.)

opt, cov, infodict, mesg, ier = spopt.leastsq(residual, p_guess, poiss_err(H), args = coords, maxfev = 100000, full_output = True)
```

Here's my data, just with fewer bins:

```
[[  1.00000000e+01   1.10000000e+01   2.10000000e+01   1.90000000e+01
1.70000000e+01   2.10000000e+01   2.40000000e+01   1.90000000e+01
2.80000000e+01   1.90000000e+01]
[  1.40000000e+01   4.50000000e+01   6.00000000e+01   6.80000000e+01
1.34000000e+02   1.97000000e+02   2.23000000e+02   2.90000000e+02
3.23000000e+02   3.03000000e+02]
[  3.00000000e+01   1.17000000e+02   3.78000000e+02   9.74000000e+02
1.71900000e+03   2.27700000e+03   2.39000000e+03   2.25500000e+03
1.85600000e+03   1.31000000e+03]
[  1.52000000e+02   9.32000000e+02   2.89000000e+03   5.23800000e+03
6.66200000e+03   6.19100000e+03   4.54900000e+03   3.14600000e+03
2.09000000e+03   1.33800000e+03]
[  5.39000000e+02   2.58100000e+03   6.51300000e+03   8.89900000e+03
8.52900000e+03   6.22900000e+03   3.55000000e+03   2.14300000e+03
1.19000000e+03   6.92000000e+02]
[  1.49600000e+03   4.49200000e+03   8.77200000e+03   1.07610000e+04
9.76700000e+03   7.04900000e+03   4.23200000e+03   2.47200000e+03
1.41500000e+03   7.02000000e+02]
[  2.31800000e+03   7.01500000e+03   1.28870000e+04   1.50840000e+04
1.35590000e+04   8.55600000e+03   4.15600000e+03   1.77100000e+03
6.57000000e+02   2.55000000e+02]
[  1.57500000e+03   3.79300000e+03   5.20900000e+03   4.77800000e+03
3.26600000e+03   1.44700000e+03   5.31000000e+02   1.85000000e+02
9.30000000e+01   4.90000000e+01]
[  7.01000000e+02   1.21600000e+03   1.17600000e+03   7.93000000e+02
4.79000000e+02   2.02000000e+02   8.80000000e+01   3.90000000e+01
2.30000000e+01   1.90000000e+01]
[  2.93000000e+02   3.93000000e+02   2.90000000e+02   1.97000000e+02
1.18000000e+02   6.40000000e+01   4.10000000e+01   1.20000000e+01
1.10000000e+01   4.00000000e+00]]
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: would you mind labeling your data? e.g. the independent and dependent variables in the section above.

Comment: Added some comments to explain x and y

Comment: no i mean your code isn't even runnable at the moment and you haven't labeled it in order to make it easily runnable. The best code snippets are short ones that can be replicated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what `leastsq` does is try to:

> "Minimize the sum of squares of a set of equations"
>       -[scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq)

as it says it's minimizing a set of functions and therefore doesn't actually take any x or y data inputs in the easiest manner  if you look at the arguments [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq) so you can do it as you like and pass a residual function however, it's significantly easier to just use `curve_fit` which does it for you :) and creates the necessary equations

For fitting you should use: [`curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) if you are ok with the generic residual they use which is actually the function you pass itself `res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)` if you look in the [code here.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.12.0/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L432)

e.g. If I fit the rosenbrock function in 2d and guess the y-parameter:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from itertools import imap
import numpy as np
# use only an even number of arguments
def rosen2d(x,a):
    return (1-x)**2 + 100*(a - (x**2))**2
#generate some random data slightly off

datax = np.array([.01*x for x in range(-10,10)])
datay = 2.3
dataz = np.array(map(lambda x: rosen2d(x,datay), datax))
optimalparams, covmatrix = curve_fit(rosen2d, datax, dataz)
print 'opt:',optimalparams
```

fitting the colville function in 4d:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

# 4 dimensional colville function
# definition from http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/colville.html
def colville(x,x3,x4):
    x1,x2 = x[:,0],x[:,1]
    return 100*(x1**2 - x2)**2 + (x1-1)**2 + (x3-1)**2 + \
            90*(x3**2 - x4)**2 + \
            10.1*((x2 - 1)**2 + (x4 - 1)**2) + \
            19.8*(x2 - 1)*(x4 - 1)
#generate some random data slightly off

datax = np.array([[x,x] for x in range(-10,10)])
#add gaussian noise
datax+= np.random.rand(*datax.shape)
#set 2 of the 4 parameters to constants
x3 = 3.5
x4 = 4.5
#calculate the function
dataz = colville(datax, x3, x4)
#fit the function
optimalparams, covmatrix = curve_fit(colville, datax, dataz)
print 'opt:',optimalparams
```

Using a custom residual function:

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import numpy as np

# 4 dimensional colville function
# definition from http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/colville.html
def colville(x,x3,x4):
    x1,x2 = x[:,0],x[:,1]
    return 100*(x1**2 - x2)**2 + (x1-1)**2 + (x3-1)**2 + \
            90*(x3**2 - x4)**2 + \
            10.1*((x2 - 1)**2 + (x4 - 1)**2) + \
            19.8*(x2 - 1)*(x4 - 1)
#generate some random data slightly off


datax = np.array([[x,x] for x in range(-10,10)])
#add gaussian noise
datax+= np.random.rand(*datax.shape)
#set 2 of the 4 parameters to constants
x3 = 3.5
x4 = 4.5

def residual(p, x, y):
    return y - colville(x,*p)
#calculate the function
dataz = colville(datax, x3, x4)
#guess some initial parameter values
p0 = [0,0]
#calculate a minimization of the residual
optimalparams = leastsq(residual, p0, args=(datax, dataz))[0]
print 'opt:',optimalparams
```

Edit: you used both the position and the keyword arg for `args`: if you look at the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq) you'll see it uses position 3, but also can be used as a keyword argument. You used *both* which means the function is as expected, confused.

Comment: I understand what leastsq does, and I am using it because I can define a custom residual (eventually, I will incorporate parameter constraints).  So, the data in my second block of code is the dependent variable, which I am trying to fit with a function that takes x & y to H. An example using this technique is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588371/scipy-leastsq-goodness-of-fit-estimator).  I am given to understand that 'Params' are passed to 'residual' as part of the fitting, and 'args' are simply used as inputs for the fit.  My issue is that I am getting the above TypeError.

Comment: @Eiyrioü  Hi, how can I be able to get your mail id or contact ? I'm running into a deep trouble with finding best-fitted-surface-function. A little help would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: I apologize, I don't give that out - try asking a question with the scipy tag?