# Passing 2D argument into numpy.optimize.fmin error

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I currently have a function `PushLogUtility(p,w,f)` that I am looking to optimise w.r.t `f` (2xk) list for fixed `p` (9xk list) and `w` (2xk) list.

I am using the `scipy.optimize.fmin` function but am getting errors I believe because `f` is 2-dimensional. I had written a previous function `LogUtility(p,q,f)` passing a 1-dimensional input and it worked.

One option it seems is to write the `p`, `w` and `f` into 1-dimensional lists but this would be time-consuming and less readable. Is there any way to make `fmin` optimise a function with a 2D input?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is in fact impossible to pass a 2D list to `numpy.optimize.fmin`. However flattening the input `f` was not that much of a problem and while it makes the code slightly uglier, the optimisation now works.

Interestingly I also coded the optimisation in Matlab which does take 2D inputs to its `fminsearch` function. Both programs give the same output (y).